# preg_match regex with specific string structure

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

EDIT:
I will receive user input which can be any string.
I only want to flag those strings that have a certain structure.

```
// Flag
$subject = 'Name 1 : text / Name 2 : text';

// Flag
$subject = 'Name 1 : text / Name 2 : text / Name 3';

// Flag
$subject = 'Name 3 / Name 2 / Name 3';

// Do NOT flag
$subject = 'Name 1 : text, Name 2, text, Name 3';

// Do NOT flag
$subject = 'This is another string';
```

So basically flagging every string that has at least 1 forward slash.
Can this be done with regular expression?
Thanks!

Comment: Are you looking for [`explode(' : ', $subject)`](http://www.php.net/explode)?

Comment: I'm looking for regular expression pattern

Comment: What output do you want? What are the rules? What have you tried?

Comment: Well the strings may very. E.g another string could be "Hello this is a string". I want to check if the string matches the $subject structure then I use explode and generate links from Name 1, Name 2, Name 3, otherwise leave it as it is.

Comment: "the same structure" is open to many interpretations... And a missing ` : text` portion in the last string could easily mean 'different structure', unless you want a _very_ clever algorithm detecting 'optionals'.

Comment: I want to check if there's any / first, and then check if there's any : between slashes.

Comment: It sounds like you should go with h2ooooooo's idea and use `explode`. First on the `/` character, and then on `:`.

Comment: So you can't use anything else as `name` and `text` but the letters from `a-z` upper and lower case, digits `0-9` and spaces? `Name 1 / This is my text! It is nice!` should fail?

Answer (score 1):

I might very well have misunderstood what is it you want, but I think this might be what you want (no regex):

```
<?php
    $subject = 'Name 1 : text / Name 2 : text / Name 3';

    $subjectArray = array();
    $explode = explode(' / ', $subject);
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($explode); $i++) {
        list($name, $text) = explode(' : ', $explode[$i]);
        $subjectArray[] = array(
            'name' => $name,
            'text' => $text
        );
    }
    print_r($subjectArray);
?>
```

which will output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [name] => Name 1
            [text] => text
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [name] => Name 2
            [text] => text
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [name] => Name 3
            [text] => 
        )

)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to define your rules of `same structure` clearly but just to get you started following reges will work for both of your examples:

```
$re='#^Name\s+\d+\s*:\s*\w+\s*/\s*Name\s+\d+\s*:\s*\w+(?:\s*/\s*Name\s+\d+)?$#i';
if (preg_match($re, $str, $match))
   print_r($match);
```